# ModuleNotFoundError while trying to create a custom package that should work as command line script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, command-line-interface, packaging

I'd like to be able to execute `trump` and get a random quote using a rest api.
**NOTE:** No python before trump

I have the following directory structure -

```
trump  
|--setup.py  
|--trump  
   |-- quote.py
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- __main__.py
```

`setup.py` contains -

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] != 3:
    raise RuntimeError('Unsupported python version "{0}"'.format(sys.version_info[0]))

setup(name='trump',
      version='0.1',
      description='Trumps tweets',
      keywords=['trump'],
      #include_package_data=True,
      packages=find_packages('trump'),
      package_dir={'':'trump'},
      license='GNU GPL v3',
      python_requires="!=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*",
      install_requires=[
          'requests',
      ],
      entry_points = {
            'console_scripts': [
                'trump = trump.__main__:main'
          ]
      },
      zip_safe=False
      )
```

`__init__.py` is empty.
`__main__.py` contains -

```
import quote
def main():
    quote.vomit()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

And `quote.py` contains -

```
import requests

def vomit():
    api_response = requests.get('http://api.tronalddump.io/random/quote')
    quote = api_response.json()['value']

    print(quote)
```

In root directory when I run `python3 trump` then I get correct results. However when I install it via pip as `pip3 install --user -e .` and then try to execute `trump`, I get the following error -

```
 $ trump
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/walker/.local/bin/trump", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('trump', 'console_scripts', 'trump')()
  File "/home/walker/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 487, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/walker/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2728, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/walker/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2346, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/walker/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2352, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trump'
```

I have tried to follow [python packaging docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html) but can't seem to figure out why is this happening.

EDIT:
After doing `packages=find_packages()` I get the following error-

```
$ pip install --user -e .
Obtaining file:///trump
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    writing trump/trump.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to trump/trump.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to trump/trump.egg-info/entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to trump/trump.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to trump/trump.egg-info/top_level.txt
    error: package directory 'trump/trump' does not exist

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /trump/
```

This leads me to believe that my configuration for `package_dir` and `packages` is wrong. But the issue is that if I comment `package_dir` line and in either case of `package`(having trump or empty) i get the following response -

```
$ trump
bash: trump: command not found
```

Comment: Ironically your trump program tell two conflicting stories of what Python version it needs.

Comment: @KlausD.  Not quite. Look carefully, I am accessing just the major version by `[0]`. So for python versions 3.5 and onwards, it will work.

Comment: You condition allows version 3 only, while your `python_requires` allows version 2.7.

Comment: @KlausD. correct. Fixed it now....but that is actually unrelated to the error. I reinstalled and checked it again, it gave the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `'trump'` from `packages=find_packages('trump')`. `'trump'` is the package you want to include into the distribution, while `find_packages('trump')` looks inside `trump/` directory, doesn't find any packages there and returns an empty list.

```
packages=find_packages()
```

Also you don't need `package_dir` at all. It'd be used in case where you have `trump/` subdirectory inside, say, `src/` so you'd use

package_dir={'': 'src'},

Comment: Unfortunately that gave me another error that I have mentioned in EDIT. This has narrowed it down to 2 statements i.e the error is happening because of either `package_dir` or `package`

Comment: You don't need `package_dir` at all.

Comment: Problem is, I have already commented that. And I only have `packages=find_packages()` as you mentioned , after that when I try installing it it installs without any error but running trump gives me this `bash: trump: command not found`

Comment: As it turns out the problem was something more fundamental, I was using `trump` as directory name as well as module name. I think  python was confused because of that. Once I changed the names, it worked.